# Spring Data performance issues after upgrade spring-boot-1.5.20 -> spring-boot-2.1.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, query-performance

For a long time we used "spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE" and decided to update it to "spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE".
After that we've faced databases performance issues. We thought that it's because of mongodb driver, but in redis there are the same issues. Execution time for all queries was increased up to 5-10 times.

Did anybody meet the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

We faced a similar issue after upgrading from 2.0.8 to 2.1.4 but couldn't really find the problem. So we decided to downgrade to 2.1.3 and see what happens. 
The performance returned back to normal levels, so we decided to stick to it for the time being.
This might not be the most satisfying answer, but if all else fails you might want to give 2.1.3 a shot.

EDIT
Since the jump from 1.5 to 2.1 is quite a big one, you might also want to check out the migration guides to make sure you didn't miss anything.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-2.0-to-2.1-Migration-Guide