# Spring Data query performance issue after upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, query-performance

After updating from spring-boot 2.0.5.RELEASE to spring-boot 2.1.3.RELEASE some unchanged queries to a MySQL DB are lasting between 3 and 5x longer. I have tried the following.

- Run YourKit Java profiler. Found the problem was on a `SELECT *` SQL statement.
- Try different spring-boot versions (2.1.0.RELEASE, 2.1.4.RELEASE). No improvements, the performance increases only in versions < 2.1
- Try downgrading other 3rd party libraries that have been changed in the 2.1.3 release notes (HikariCP, Tomcat, etc.)
- Related question: [Spring Data performance issues after upgrade spring-boot-1.5.20 -> spring-boot-2.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871654/spring-data-performance-issues-after-upgrade-spring-boot-1-5-20-spring-boot-2)

Any idea of why this could be happening? I can't open an issue in `spring-data-jpa` GitHub repository.

Comment: Are the queries exactly the same?

Comment: Issues for Spring Data JPA go here: https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJPA

Comment: We actually just fixed a performance issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1534 could you give the latest snapshot a try and let me know if that solves the problem?